# How to I keep track of changes in FLA file (via version control)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, svn, version-control

I have all of my files in version control (SVN subversion). FLA file is not a text file, so when I change it and check it in, there isn't a way to see what has changed inside of FLA.

Is there a way to keep track of changes to FLA file and it's contents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flash CS5 has introduced a new file format called **XFL** which has been designed for use with version control systems. This format basically splits up your FLA file into a series of separate XML data files (all contained within the one folder) which means version control systems can accurately determine what parts of the file have changed.

Simply go to File > Save AS, and select **xfl** from the drop-down list.

If you're using anything before CS5, then unfortunately there is no similar way to accomplish this task. I will add, however, that if this is the case, then you can try and mitigate this problem by keeping all your code in an external AS file and load any data from external xml/image/etc. files. This way, there is at least some degree of tracking for certain parts of your project.

Comment: Awesome. Is there something I can do to automatically save a XFL copy everytime a change to FLA is made?

Comment: XFL replaces your FLA file. So once you've saved them all as an XFL, you can safely delete all your old FLA files and modify the XFL directly. This way you only have to hit 'save'.

Comment: In the past, we avoided using Flash because of version control unfriendliness and switched to Silverlight.

Comment: @linquize wow, it was really stupid. like switching to SVG over PNG images because they are version control friendly.

Comment: A collection of text files in a file system (Silverlight) is always easier to manage than the FLA way